# The admin option doesn't show up next to my like button

Tags: facebook-like, admin, facebook-page

I have a problem. I created an app in FB and then with that app I created a like button. FB says that I should see an admin link next to my like button on my website when I am logged in.

I have fb:app_id and fb:admins set up in meta, still I don'see the link. I would need it for two reason.

One is to acces the admin of the page so I can send messages for people who liked my site, also I want to set up a fanpage and once I could access the admin of the website likes according to the facebook documentation I could turn it into a fan page (FB page) this way not loosing the likes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is deprecated, there's a [migration guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/) on Facebook's developer site explaining how to move your OG pages to regular pages if you want to maintain part of that functionality